# How to print 1 to 100 without any looping using C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I am trying to print numbers from 1 to 100 without using loops, using C#. Any clues?

Comment: If this is for an assignment, what constructs have you been taught so far?  This will help formulate answers.

Comment: Have you got to recursion yet in the class or is this the first homework assignment?

Comment: Whew.  This question was viewed 99 times when I found it.  Glad I missed the corner case.

Comment: @Not a real question voters: This is a real question. In case it's not clear, repharsed slightly: "How do I print the integers from 1 to 100 without using a loop? TIA."

Comment: Why has this been closed? This is a total valid & real question.

Comment: They just don't like such simple questions, I think. ;-)

Comment: @Henk: Not even remotely relevant.

Comment: It is a programming question however. I think there should be a definition of what is not a real question. We all started from somewhere remember. It think this community should be able to carry along programmers of different experience levels

Comment: @Colour Blend: Agreed, as long as the person asking the question shows that they have at least made an effort to solve the problem first. Otherwise, they're learning nothing, but will pass their classes; then you and I end up maintaining the programs they've "written". That's not something I want to do - do you?

Comment: This question is not the same as fair beginner question such as "How do I 'unroll' a loop?"  It's obviously a puzzle question.  That's why there is debate over if it should be closed.

Comment: See Recursion                                           .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044033/display-numbers-from-1-to-100-without-loops-or-conditions Are you two in the same class? If so, why do one want it in C# while the other in Java

Comment: (would be better on code golf)

Comment: Console.Write("001,010,011,100");

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Recursion maybe?

```
public static void PrintNext(i) {
    if (i <= 100) {
        Console.Write(i + " ");
        PrintNext(i + 1);
    }
}

public static void Main() {
    PrintNext(1);
}
```

Comment: Gratuitous "but first you have to understand recursion" comment.

Comment: Recursion generally isn't considered a loop, even though its behaving similar to a loop.

Comment: Guess I need to read about Recursion.  +1 for the help, thank you.

Comment: Although strictly not a loop, it's still using an incremental counter and a limit, so it's a clumsy loop ;)

Comment: A loop generally implies a mutable counter, this one doesn't have that (every invocation has its own "counter").

Comment: @Cecil: I don't think Noam Chomsky would think that

Comment: Recursion is more general than a loop.

Comment: Couldn't you have simply called Main() recursively?

Comment: When I first started learning recursion I got a stack overflow in my brain.

Answer (score 200):

No loops, no conditionals, and no hardcoded literal output, aka "divide and conquer FTW" solution:

```
class P
{
    static int n;

    static void P1() { System.Console.WriteLine(++n); }

    static void P2() { P1(); P1(); }

    static void P4() { P2(); P2(); }

    static void P8() { P4(); P4(); }

    static void P16() { P8(); P8(); }

    static void P32() { P16(); P16(); }

    static void P64() { P32(); P32(); }

    static void Main() { P64(); P32(); P4(); }
}
```

Alternative approach:

```
using System;

class C
{
    static int n;

    static void P() { Console.WriteLine(++n); }

    static void X2(Action a) { a(); a(); }

    static void X5(Action a) { X2(a); X2(a); a(); }

    static void Main() { X2(() => X5(() => X2(() => X5(P)))); }
}
```

Comment: This is innovative, but I see it as valuable as writing down 100 `WriteLine` statements :)

Comment: Clever, but then the next question will be how to print 1 to 101. How do you handle prime numbers?

Comment: @Ozan: 1 to 101 is { P64(); P32(); P4(); P1(); }, 1 to 7 is { P4(); P2(); P1(); }.

Comment: I love the power of two ladder approach for this. Very clever. I also like the lambda recursion model. But you should make your answer complete by also showing a self-attenuating closure.

Comment: @LBushkin: you can really think of the power of two ladder as or-ing together bit flags. 100 = 0b1100100, 64 = 0b1000000, 32 = 0b0100000, and 4 = 0b0000100, so 64 | 32 | 4 = 100. Coolness!

Comment: @LBushkin: I'm not sure what you mean by "self-attenuating closure"; can you clarify (or maybe just post it as a separate answer)?

Comment: This is amazing, Can you give some explanation on this please, I was just confused

Comment: @User Try stepping through it in the debugger, it should be pretty straightforward how it works there.

Answer (score 66):

```
Console.Out.WriteLine('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100');
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this only prints 5 numbers, not all 100.

Comment: I hope that Adam was joking in his comment. Of course it only prints 5 numbers. It's just shorthand.

Comment: Of course you wouldn't need to write the shorthand if you make a code to write the output with a for loop, then copy the full output into the answer here...

Answer (score 46):

One more:

```
Console.WriteLine(
   String.Join(
      ", ", 
      Array.ConvertAll<int, string>(
         Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray(), 
         i => i.ToString()
      )
   )
);
```

Comment: `String.Join` is a nice solution, indeed! How didn't it come to my mind immediately?

Comment: String.Join, Array.ConvertAll, Enumerable.Range and ToArray all use for/foreach constructs. You can't just encapsulate them and claim there is no looping!

Comment: @Callum, there are no loop constructs in my C# code as requested. :) This answer is all about plausible deniability and how to make the printed output look prettier using `String.Join`.

Answer (score 14):

```
using static IronRuby.Ruby;

class Print1To100WithoutLoopsDemo
{
    static void Main() => 
      CreateEngine().Execute("(1..100).each {|i| System::Console.write_line i }");
}
```

Hey, why not?

Comment: The answer to all C# questions.

Comment: Ruby's .each would be a loop, or?

Comment: @gerrit: The Ruby Language Specification doesn't say how to implement `Range#each`. It is perfectly possible to implement it with recursion, for example. Besides, if you *really* want to dig down into the implementation, then even using a `for` loop counts as "without loop", since it will eventually be compiled into `GOTO`s anyway.

Comment: Hm, that makes the original question poorly defined then, or not?

Comment: @gerrit: As most homework questions tend to be. Depending on what exactly the teacher is trying to teach, they probably expect the students to either use (tail) recursion or `GOTO` to solve this assignment, but: both are isomorphic to loops, so, saying you can't use anything which smells like a loop kind of defeats the purpose of this exercise.

Answer (score 12):

```
Console.WriteLine('1');
Console.WriteLine('2');
...
Console.WriteLine('100');
```

...Or would you have accepted a recursive solution?

EDIT: or you could do this and use a variable:

```
int x = 1;
Console.WriteLine(x);
x+=1;
Console.WriteLine('2');
x+=1;
...
x+=1
Console.WriteLine('100');
```

Comment: +1 for the recursive idea.  Even though it's a bit abusive of the stack, it would work and it's only an assignment, presumably.

Comment: I haven't done C# in awhile, but couldn't you just just do Console.WriteLine( ++x ); instead of doing x += 1 before each line? (Obviously initializing the variable beforehand.

Comment: You could even use the variable the other 99 times!  ;-)

Comment: @Jim: yes, I'm a bit TOO quick with the copy/paste.

I also had an idea to use events: Increase x, raise an event whose listener prints the event arg (which contains x).

I see the recursive solution was the selected answer. I had hoped someone would submit a lambda solution. ;)

Answer (score 12):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
    .Select(i => i.ToString())
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

Not sure if this counts as the loop is kind of hidden, but if it's legit it's an idiomatic solution to the problem. Otherwise you can do this.

```
    int count = 1;
top:
    if (count > 100) { goto bottom; }
    Console.WriteLine(count++);
    goto top;
bottom:
```

Of course, this is effectively what a loop will be translated to anyway but it's certainly frowned upon these days to write code like this.

Answer (score 9):

No loops, no recursion, just a hashtable-like array of functions to choose how to branch:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Juliet
{
    class PrintStateMachine
    {
        int state;
        int max;
        Action<Action>[] actions;

        public PrintStateMachine(int max)
        {
            this.state = 0;
            this.max = max;
            this.actions = new Action<Action>[] { IncrPrint, Stop };
        }

        void IncrPrint(Action next)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(++state);
            next();
        }

        void Stop(Action next) { }

        public void Start()
        {
            Action<Action> action = actions[Math.Sign(state - max) + 1];
            action(Start);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrintStateMachine printer = new PrintStateMachine(100);
            printer.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

Here's a breakdown of what is happening in the above code:

- [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) returns the specified range of integral numbers as IEnumerator<Int32>
- [Enumerable.ToList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) converts an IEnumerable<T> into a List<T>
- [List<T>.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) takes a lamdba function and invokes it for each item in the list

**Performance Consideration**

The ToList call will cause memory to be allocated for all items (in the above example 100 ints).  This means O(N) space complexity.  If this is a concern in your app i.e. if the range of integers can be very high, then you should avoid ToList and enumerate the items directly.

Unfortunately ForEach is not part of the IEnumerable extensions provided out of the box (hence the need to convert to List in the above example).  Fortunately this is fairly easy to create:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> func)
    {
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            func(item);
        }
    }
}
```

With the above IEnumerable extension in place, now in all the places where you need to apply an action to an IEnumerable you can simply call ForEach with a lambda.  So now the original example looks like this:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

The only difference is that we no longer call ToList, and this results in constant (O(1)) space usage... which would be a quite noticeable gain if you were processing a really large number of items.

Comment: Yea, but there's a loop in there!

Comment: You can even pass a method group: `Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Answer (score 8):

By the time I answer this, someone will already have it, so here it is anyway, with credit to Caleb:

```
void Main()
{
    print(0, 100);
}

public void print(int x, int limit)
{
    Console.WriteLine(++x);
    if(x != limit)
        print(x, limit);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just for the ugly literal interpretation:

```
Console.WriteLine("numbers from 1 to 100 without using loops, ");
```

(you can laugh now or later, or not)

Answer (score 7):

I can think of two ways. One of them involves about 100 lines of code!

There's another way to reuse a bit of code several times without using a while/for loop...

Hint: Make a function that prints the numbers from 1 to N. It should be easy to make it work for N = 1. Then think about how to make it work for N = 2.

Answer (score 7):

With **regular expressions**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Hello1
{
   public static void Main()
   {

      // Count to 128 in unary
      string numbers = "x\n";
      numbers += Regex.Replace(numbers, "x+\n", "x$&");
      numbers += Regex.Replace(numbers, "x+\n", "xx$&");
      numbers += Regex.Replace(numbers, "x+\n", "xxxx$&");
      numbers += Regex.Replace(numbers, "x+\n", "xxxxxxxx$&");
      numbers += Regex.Replace(numbers, "x+\n", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$&");
      numbers += Regex.Replace(numbers, "x+\n", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$&");
      numbers += Regex.Replace(numbers, "x+\n", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$&");

      // Out of 1..128, select 1..100
      numbers = Regex.Match(numbers, "(.*\n){100}").Value;

      // Convert from unary to decimal
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "x{10}", "<10>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "x{9}", "<9>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "x{8}", "<8>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "x{7}", "<7>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "x{6}", "<6>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "x{5}", "<5>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "x{4}", "<4>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "x{3}", "<3>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "x{2}", "<2>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "x{1}", "<1>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "(<10>){10}", "<100>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "(<10>){9}", "<90>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "(<10>){8}", "<80>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "(<10>){7}", "<70>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "(<10>){6}", "<60>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "(<10>){5}", "<50>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "(<10>){4}", "<40>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "(<10>){3}", "<30>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "(<10>){2}", "<20>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "(<[0-9]{3}>)$", "$1<00>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "(<[0-9]{2}>)$", "$1<0>");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "<([0-9]0)>\n", "$1\n");
      numbers = Regex.Replace(numbers, "<([0-9])0*>", "$1");

      System.Console.WriteLine(numbers);

   }
}
```

The output:

```
# => 1
# => 2
# ...
# => 99
# => 100
```

Comment: By which I guess you mean: "I'd give you as many +1's as the system would allow, but I'm sort of busy hammering a pencil into my brain with Knuth vol. 1.  Thanks a lot."

Comment: @Luke, I guess it *is* important that insanity follow the rules.  Better now?

Answer (score 5):

Method A:

```
Console.WriteLine('1');
Console.WriteLine('print 2');
Console.WriteLine('print 3');
...
Console.WriteLine('print 100');
```

Method B:

```
func x (int j)
{
  Console.WriteLine(j);
  if (j < 100)
     x (j+1);
}

x(1);
```

Comment: I really don't want to downvote on such a silly question, but he did say using c#. :)

Comment: @Donnie, this *seems* to be a homework question, which means users are encouraged to not give the exact code, but rather enough of a push in the right direction for the OP to figure it out, which I think @wallyk has done quite well. +1

Comment: @Brandon, fair enough.  And I didn't downvote either, was just saying :)

Answer (score 5):

Just LINQ it...

```
Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
                            .Select(s => s.ToString())
                            .Aggregate((x, y) => x + "," + y));
```

Comment: wouldn't this be in turn translated into a while loop anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I can think two ways:

- using 100 `Console.WriteLine`
- using `goto` in a `switch` statement

Answer (score 2):

A completely unnecessary method:

```
int i = 1;
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1);
t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(
  (sender, e) => { if (i > 100) t.Enabled = false; else Console.WriteLine(i++); });
t.Enabled = true;
Thread.Sleep(110);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Main()
{
  printNumber(1);
}

private void printNumber(int x)
{
  Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
  if(x<101)
  {
    x+=1;
    printNumber(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: LOl posted a similar answer 8 seconds after you :(

Comment: shouldn't x be incremented? :D

Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

The cool and funny way:

```
static void F(int[] array, int n)
{
    Console.WriteLine(array[n] = n);
    F(array, n + 1);
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try { F(new int[101], 1); }
    catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static int temp = 0;

    public static int a()
    {
        temp = temp + 1;

        if (temp == 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(temp);
            return 0;
        }

        else
            Console.WriteLine(temp);

        Program.a();
        return 0;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Program.a();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less pseudo code I havent done c# in years, PS running on 1 hour of sleep so i might be wrong.

```
int i = 0;

public void printNum(j){       
    if(j > 100){
        break;
    } else {
        print(j);
        printNum(j + 1);
    }
}
public void main(){
    print(i);
    printNum(i + 1);       
}
```

Comment: You want `return;` instead of `break;` in your edge case.  And `print()` isn't the correct function -- presumably you want `Console.WriteLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintNum(1);
private void PrintNum(int i)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
   if(i < 100)
   {
      PrintNum(i+1);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Print(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList(), 0);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        public static void Print(List<int> numbers, int currentPosition) {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[currentPosition]);
            if (currentPosition < numbers.Count - 1) {
                Print(numbers, currentPosition + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is in thread [2045637](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044033/display-numbers-from-1-to-100-without-loops-or-conditions/2045637#2045637), which asks the same question for Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static Timer s = new Timer();
    static int i = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        s.Elapsed += Restart;
        s.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void Restart(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        s.Dispose();
        if (i < 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(++i);
            s = new Timer(1);
            s.Elapsed += Restart;
            s.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

You must notice that I'm **NOT** using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Feeling a bit naughty posting this:

```
   private static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (s, e) =>
        {
            var frames = new StackTrace().GetFrames();
            Console.Write($"{frames.Length - 2} ");
            var frame = frames[101];
        };

        throw new Exception();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [Test]
    public void PrintNumbersNoLoopOrRecursionTest()
    {
        var numberContext = new NumberContext(100);

        numberContext.OnNumberChange += OnNumberChange(numberContext);
        numberContext.CurrentNumber = 1;
    }

    OnNumberChangeHandler OnNumberChange(NumberContext numberContext)
    {
        return (o, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Counter > numberContext.LastNumber)
                return;

            Console.WriteLine(numberContext.CurrentNumber);

            args.Counter += 1;
            numberContext.CurrentNumber = args.Counter;
        };
    }


public delegate void OnNumberChangeHandler(object source, OnNumberChangeEventArgs e);
public class NumberContext
{
    public NumberContext(int lastNumber)
    {
        LastNumber = lastNumber;
    }

    public event OnNumberChangeHandler OnNumberChange;
    private int currentNumber;
    public int CurrentNumber
    {
        get { return currentNumber; }
        set {
            currentNumber = value;
            OnNumberChange(this, new OnNumberChangeEventArgs(value));
        }
    }

    public int LastNumber { get; set; }

    public class OnNumberChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public OnNumberChangeEventArgs(int counter)
        {
            Counter = counter;
        }

        public int Counter { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            print(0);
        }

        public static void print(int i)
        {
            if (i >= 0 && i<=10)
            {

                i = i + 1;
                Console.WriteLine(i + " ");
                print(i);
            }
}
```

Comment: What is the diffenerence of this solution in comparison to the accepted answer?