# Print 1 to 10 without any loop in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display numbers from 1 to 100 without loops or conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044033/display-numbers-from-1-to-100-without-loops-or-conditions)

Interview question:

Print 1 to 10 without any loop in java.

Comment: System.out.println("1 to 10");...:D

Comment: *"Interview question:"*  What was *your* answer?  Are are you typing this question on your mobile, hoping for an answer before the interviewer returns?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simple way: `System.out.println` the values:

```
    System.out.println(1);
    System.out.println(2);
    System.out.println(3);
    System.out.println(4);
    System.out.println(5);
    System.out.println(6);
    System.out.println(7);
    System.out.println(8);
    System.out.println(9);
    System.out.println(10);
```

Complex way: use recursion

```
public void recursiveMe(int n) {
    if(n <= 10) {// 10 is the max limit
        System.out.println(n);//print n
        recursiveMe(n+1);//call recursiveMe with n=n+1
    }
}
recursiveMe(1); // call the function with 1.
```

Comment: How did you do this in 26 freaking seconds?

Comment: Because of Eclipse !!! :p I love Eclipse.

Comment: @HarryJoy: your eclipse works with speed of light it seems...:D

Comment: @HarryJoy congrats bro for your speed and also using Eclipse :)

Comment: just write syso then ctrl+space. then alt+down to duplicate. Then type recursiveMe somewhere and press ctrl+space. Then write and if condition and syso. It's so easy and fast.

Comment: May be I'm fast but not as *Jon Skeet*.

Comment: btw, my +1 was for the lightning speed, not for "The answer is useful". :-P jk...

Comment: And what is your relation to Mark?

Comment: I am not believing this short difference in time!!! and never justifying my mind to accept this (26 sec!)!!

Answer (score 4):

If you like your programs obtuse, no loops, condition statements or main method.

```
static int i = 0;
static {
    try {
        recurse();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private static void recurse() {
    System.out.print(++i + 0 / (i - 11) + " ");
    recurse();
}
```

---

This uses a loop but may be an interesting answer

```
Random random = new Random(-6732303926L);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.print((1+random.nextInt(10))+" ");
}
```

You can restructure this to not use a loop.