# Print character multiple times

Tags: java, string, character

How can I print a character multiple times in a single line? This means I cannot use a loop.

I'm trying to print `" _"` multiple times.

I tried this method but it's not working:

```
System.out.println (" _" , s);
```

`s` is the variable.

Comment: `System.out.println('_____');` ;-)

Comment: Be in the habit of checking the APIs. I see no example of this method in the [Java 7 API docs for System.out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out).

Comment: "This means I cannot use a loop." How so?

Comment: @ceejayoz That is a bit long for a character literal. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can print in the same line with `System.out.print(" _");` so you **can** use a loop. `print` instead of `println` does not append a new line character.

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    System.out.print(" _");
}
```

Will print: `_ _ _ _ _`.

Comment: The post states no loops

Comment: I understand that the no loop condition is consecuence of the need to print in the same line (println doesn't allow it but print does).

Comment: @Econy3 you stated no loops in the question?

Comment: @Growler yeah, but that was cuz I wanted in a single line. Paco explained the concept of "println" and "print".

Answer (score 10):

If you can use external libraries, [`StringUtils.repeat`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat(char%2C%20int)) sounds perfect for you:

```
int s = 5;
System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat('_', s));
```

EDIT:
To answer the question in the comments - `StringUtils.repeat` takes two parameters - the `char` you want to repeat and the number of times you want it, and returns a `String` composed of that repetition. So, in the example above, it will return a string of five underscores, `_____`.

Comment: Can you explain me how can I use StringUtils.repeat ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the new Stream API to achieve that. There always be an iteration behind the scenes, but this is one possible implementation.

```
Stream.generate(() -> " _").limit(5).forEach(System.out::print); // _ _ _ _ _
```

Comment: Stream API. It never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: ... or  also `IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(i -> System.out.print(" _"));`

Answer (score 1):

With one call to `print`/`println`, and using your variable "s":

```
System.out.println(Stream.generate(() -> " _").limit(s).collect(Collectors.joining()))
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a shortcut like what you've posted...

And what do you mean "In a single line"?

If in one line of code... see Mureinik's answer

If print "_" in one line:

Instead:

[Print 1 to 10 without any loop in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408210/print-1-to-10-without-any-loop-in-java)

```
    System.out.print("_");
    System.out.print("_");
    System.out.print("_");
    System.out.print("_");
    System.out.print("_");
```

Or

```
public void recursiveMe(int n) {
    if(n <= 5) {// 5 is the max limit
        System.out.print("_");//print n
        recursiveMe(n+1);//call recursiveMe with n=n+1
    }
}
recursiveMe(1); // call the function with 1.
```

Comment: When stealing and modifying someone else's answer, it's wise to update the comments. Line 2 of the recursive solution should have the comment `// 5 is the max limit`

Comment: System.out.println(_); is not a valid Java statement :)

Comment: Why not System.out.println('_')? ;)

Comment: @jdv Yes it is: `int _ = 5; System.out.println(_);`

Comment: Well played. But not a valid statement /in context/. But I guess we are playing Stupid Java Tricks here.