# Display 1 to 100 without loop or recursion

Tags: java

I found the solution to this problem but can't figure out how it works. Can someone please explain this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Object[] numbers = new Object[100];
Arrays.fill(numbers, new Object() {
    private int count = 0;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(++count);
    }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
```

[I could not comment to that answer directly because I dont have enough reputation points.]

Comment: That's cheating. `Arrays.fill` has a loop, so you can't say this code is "without loop".

Comment: Probably, the question should demand the solution "without *explicit* loop or recursion".

Comment: The loop that display the numbers is not inside the one inside the 'fill' but the one inside the 'toString'

Comment: The original question referred to by OP is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044033/display-numbers-from-1-to-100-without-loops-or-conditions

Comment: Thank you guys. After reading all the answers, the solution is lot clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be accurate, `Arrays.fill()` use a loop in its own implementation.
In general, `Arrays.fill` fills an array by assigning the second parameter to every element of the first parameter (your array).

Your example has an `Array` of type `Object` and a length of 100 elements.
In  `Arrays.fill(...)` you generate a so-called anonymous class of type Object, which reimplements the `toString`-method by increasing the value of a counter (`int count`) and printing it after that.

Now, by calling `Arrays.toString` the `toString()` method of every element inside the array is executed (which is the same instance of the anonymous class here), resulting in printing the numbers from 1-100

Comment: "every Object"? It's actually always the same object and the `toString` method is executed a 100 times on this object. If each cell had it's own instance of Object you would get all 1's.

Comment: Yes. Its one object. As per documentation, `Arrays.fill(Object[] a, Object val)` assigns the reference of val to each element of the array `a`

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I should have been more accurate here. By saying every Object I meant every Object/Element inside the array. But as I mentioned in the first sentence, it is one instance which gets assigned multiple times.
I will edit it to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I was just being pedantic and I thought it might be good to be very explicit about this detail. I saw you edited your answer +1

Answer (score 4):

> Can someone please explain this?

This code is a use of

`Arrays.fill(Object[] a, Object val)`

Where the Object `val` provided is an anonymous class with its toString() method overridden.

Arrays.toString(numbers) calls the toString() on the anonymous class for each element in the `a` array. As the toString() is overridden to increment the count, you get incremented values each time it is called.

However, as @Eran has pointed out, it is not without a loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(1)
System.out.println(2)
System.out.println(3)
System.out.println(4)
System.out.println(5)
System.out.println(6)
System.out.println(7)
...
System.out.println(100)
```

:D

To avoid the code-generator proposed by Dmitry, this can be easily done with just copy-paste

```
int i=0;
System.out.println(++i);
System.out.println(++i);
System.out.println(++i);
System.out.println(++i);
System.out.println(++i);
...
System.out.println(++i);
```

- Write the `System.out.println(++i)` once.
- Copy and paste 4 times.
- Then you pick those 5 lines and copy paste them again.
- You should now have 10 times that line. Select those 10 lines and copy paste another 9 times.
- done!

Comment: The only loop is expected to be in the *code generator*, and this loop doesn't count.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are trying to tell me. What code generator are you talking about? And which loop do you mean by "this loop"?

Comment: sorry, just a joke. In order to put down all the lines `System.out.println(1);...System.out.println(100);` you, probably, want a code generator (it's a too tedious task to print out all the lines *manually*) and this generator will have a loop :). Jesting aside, the solution is nice +1

Comment: @DmitryBychenko updated: my new solution is no so tedious to do by hand ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better solution:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I think it's self explanatory

Comment: `forEach` looks pretty loopy to me.

Comment: Without loop or recursion, foreach is a loop

Comment: `Stream.forEach()` technically is not a loop. Following your logic one can say that `Arrays.fill` is loopy, because it uses a loop internally.

Comment: Nice, yet OP did not ask for a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
public class NoLoopPrint {

    int max;
    int from;

    public NoLoopPrint(int max) {
        this(1, max);
    }

    public NoLoopPrint(int from, int max) {
        this.max = max;
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (from >= max) {
            return String.valueOf(max);
        }
        System.out.println(from++);
        return this.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(new NoLoopPrint(100));
        System.out.println(new NoLoopPrint(10, 20));
    }
}
```

Comment: you must not use recursion